# Sorting an array of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Request your help on sorting an array of array in PHP as below, tried all these function ksort, usort, arsort, krsort nothing seem to be working, any help would be much appreciated.

**Original Array**

```
Array
(
    [serv1-DB] => Array
        (
            [2019-11-22] => 0
            [2019-11-23] => 0
            [2019-11-24] => 0
            [2019-11-25] => 1
            [2019-11-26] => 3
            [2019-11-27] => 3
            [2019-11-28] => 3
            [2019-11-29] => 3
        )

    [ser2-DB] => Array
        (
            [2019-11-25] => 0
            [2019-11-24] => 0
            [2019-11-22] => 0
            [2019-11-23] => 0
            [2019-11-26] => 3
            [2019-11-27] => 3
            [2019-11-28] => 3
            [2019-11-29] => 3
        )
```

**Output Required**

```
Array
(
    [serv1-DB] => Array
        (
            [2019-11-29] => 3
            [2019-11-28] => 3
            [2019-11-27] => 3
            [2019-11-26] => 3
            [2019-11-25] => 1
            [2019-11-24] => 0
            [2019-11-23] => 0
            [2019-11-22] => 0

        )

    [ser2-DB] => Array
        (
            [2019-11-29] => 3
            [2019-11-28] => 3
            [2019-11-27] => 3
            [2019-11-26] => 3
            [2019-11-25] => 0
            [2019-11-24] => 0
            [2019-11-23] => 0
            [2019-11-22] => 0

        )
```

Comment: you can use a foreach on the parent array and then sort them by key by using ksort() https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sort reversely on the arrays like this:

```
// The arrays
$arrays = array(
    "serv1-DB" => array(
        "2019-11-22" => 0,
        "2019-11-23" => 0,
        "2019-11-24" => 0,
        "2019-11-25" => 1,
        "2019-11-26" => 3,
        "2019-11-27" => 3,
        "2019-11-28" => 3,
        "2019-11-29" => 3
    ),
    "ser2-DB" => array(
        "2019-11-25" => 0,
        "2019-11-24" => 0,
        "2019-11-22" => 0,
        "2019-11-23" => 0,
        "2019-11-26" => 3,
        "2019-11-27" => 3,
        "2019-11-28" => 3,
        "2019-11-29" => 3
    )
);

// The sorting part
foreach($arrays AS $k => $array) {
    krsort($array);
    $arrays[$k] = $array;
}
```

Comment: `rsort` modifies the array given as parameter and returns a boolean (I wish it didn't, tho).

Comment: As @Progrock said, and was right, this was not the good answer, i did a typo in the answer and corrected it. Now it's the good answer.

Comment: Wow, good catch again man, my bad seriously did not tested. Thanks

Comment: @jeto did hint a while back. Got there in the end.  If you don't test it's easy to make a slip up, we've all been there.

Answer (score 3):

You want to sort the sub arrays, so you need to loop over each of them (in write mode) and sort the keys in reverse order using [`krsort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php):

```
foreach ($array as &$subArray) {
  krsort($subArray);
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/g8pBu**